# How to format an argument list for a call in services.yaml?

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a new admin class for the Sonata Media Bundle. That requires me to override a service definition. I've successfully converted most of this XML:

```
<services>
    <service id="sonata.media.admin.media" class="%sonata.media.admin.media.class%" public="true">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="%sonata.media.admin.groupname%" label_catalogue="%sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain%" label="media" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" icon="%sonata.media.admin.groupicon%"/>
        <argument/>
        <argument>%sonata.media.admin.media.entity%</argument>
        <argument>%sonata.media.admin.media.controller%</argument>
        <argument type="service" id="sonata.media.pool"/>
        <argument type="service" id="sonata.media.manager.category" on-invalid="null"/>
        <call method="setModelManager">
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.media.admin.media.manager"/>
        </call>
        <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>%sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain%</argument>
        </call>
        <call method="setTemplates">
            <argument type="collection">
                <argument key="inner_list_row">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/inner_row_media.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="outer_list_rows_mosaic">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/list_outer_rows_mosaic.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="base_list_field">@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_flat_field.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="list">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/list.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="edit">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/edit.html.twig</argument>
            </argument>
        </call>
    </service>
```

... into this yaml:

```
sonata.media.admin.media:
    class: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\ORM\MediaAdmin
    arguments:
        - ''
        - '%sonata.media.admin.media.entity%'
        - '%sonata.media.admin.media.controller%'
        - '@sonata.media.pool'
        - '@sonata.media.manager.category'
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Seiten }
    public: true
    calls:
        - [ setModelManager, [ "@sonata.media.admin.media.manager" ] ]
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [ "%sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain%" ] ]
```

The only problem is that I have no idea how to convert this code into yaml:

```
        <call method="setTemplates">
            <argument type="collection">
                <argument key="inner_list_row">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/inner_row_media.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="outer_list_rows_mosaic">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/list_outer_rows_mosaic.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="base_list_field">@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_flat_field.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="list">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/list.html.twig</argument>
                <argument key="edit">@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/edit.html.twig</argument>
            </argument>
        </call>
```

How should my yaml look?

Comment: Looks like you got something working.  Just wanted to point out that you can import xml service files in your app so there is no technical need to make this sort of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how my yaml ends up looking, with apparent success:

```
sonata.media.admin.media:
    class: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\ORM\MediaAdmin
    arguments:
        - ''
        - '%sonata.media.admin.media.entity%'
        - '%sonata.media.admin.media.controller%'
        - '@sonata.media.pool'
        - '@sonata.media.manager.category'
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Seiten }
    public: true
    calls:
        - [ setModelManager, ["@sonata.media.admin.media.manager"] ]
        - [ setTranslationDomain, ["%sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain%"] ]
        - [ setTemplates, [ inner_list_row : "@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/inner_row_media.html.twig", outer_list_rows_mosaic : "@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/list_outer_rows_mosaic.html.twig", base_list_field : "@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_flat_field.html.twig", list : "@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/list.html.twig", edit : "@SonataMedia/MediaAdmin/edit.html.twig" ] ]
```